# Authentic/Slang Talk tone of language in UI design

Tags: tone-of-voice

I have come across more than 1 website making use of a kind of tone in language that resembles street talk. It significantly differs from the ''cool nerd'' facade that most startups use, which I personally hate(most of the time).

Let me give you an example.

[image: Schnapps UI language tone]

**The underlined word says ''No marketing bullsh%it".**

These guys may have taken this a step too far, but I can't help but notice that this kind of ''authenticism'' really strikes an honest/true note for me.

I am not talking about using slang words/swear words all the time like someone with a specific kind of [Tourette's syndrome.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprolalia)

**E.g** *I am building a graphics editor that will have a ''personal assistant'' not unlike [Microsoft's PaperClip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Assistant). I am thinking for example of including a ''Shut up'' button for the user to make it hide.*

**Is this ''subtle'' use of "*authentic/completely informal**" tone of language, completely unnaceptable on your opinion?**

As I said before, I kind of love it.

I am of the opinion that it ''vents'' the emotions of the user in regards to some specific annoying things such as the image in the example. I am pretty sure that the majority of users really have that exact word - as it is in the example above - crossing their minds when they see that subscription textbox, so it creates an atmosphere of "empathetic understanding" with the user.

It also cancels that ''cool-nerd-wannabe-hipster" company feeling I have in my mind about some of the startup companies I see floating around. But that's just me.

Comment: One man's opinion: I generally find casual speech to be endearing *most* of the time.  HOWEVER, when an application is not behaving itself, it can be extremely irritating - it seems flippant, when the app should be respectful, apologetic.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the fact that you 'kinda love it' is of little practical matter when deciding upon such questions. Unless you are building the editor for yourself or are trying to represent/promote yourself via it by demonstrating your personality, which, I assume you are not, the end user and his/hers preference of style of communication should be the main consideration here.

So whom are you building it for? What kind of people are likely to use it? Would they prefer the use of slang? Is it likely that their user experience will certainly be better (without the risk of diminishing it for other users) when using such tone?

Either way I'd suggest you to be consistent. If you wan't to represent a certain personality or style of the application, do it. Do it consistently, but also don't over use it.

Be aware that you are trying to connect to your users by using sentimental approach - by expressing slang/rude tone towards features that annoy most users, e.g. - we all know the sweet talk of marketing and therefore most would agree that its not far fetched to call it *bullshit*, or we all have been significantly annoyed by Microsoft's PaperClip by offering us help on trivial matters and would definitely like it to *shut up*!

However, maybe it is more practical to not create these problems in the first place - by creating an assistant that is not annoying etc. You said it yourself - "this kind of ''authenticism'' really strikes an honest/true note for me", so be honest and use slang only if it is the most honest thing there is to say.

The biggest risk with slang talk tone here is that there is no certainty what effect it will have on the user base as a whole. Some might like it, some will consider it to be too rude or unprofessional, because it simply boils down to the personal taste.